# How to replace certain strings inside a complex input name using Jquery

Tags: jquery, input

I have the following inputs:

```
<input type="text" class="w50" name="field_id_9[rows][row_id_1][col_id_3]" value="">
<select name="field_id_11[rows][row_id_3][col_id_15]">...</select>
```

What is the most simple and efficient way to replace the string [row_id_x] with [new_row_x+1] using jquery? Other strings in the input name must be intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.attr()` , `Number()` , `.match()` , `.replace()`

```js
$("input").attr("name", function(_,attr) {
  var re = /row_id_\d+/;
  var n = Number(attr.match(re)[0].split(/[^\d+]/).pop()) + 1;
  return attr.replace(re, "new_row_" + n)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="w50" name="field_id_9[rows][row_id_1][col_id_3]" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s34o21m0/)

**Function**

```
function getNewName(name){
    //match [row_id_x]
    var rowIdExpression = new RegExp('\\[row_id_\\d\\]');
    var rowId = name.match(rowIdExpression).toString();
    //match number
    var numberExpression = new RegExp('\\d');
    var number = rowId.match(numberExpression);
    //increment & replace number to create new rowId
    var newrowId = rowId.replace(number, parseInt(number)+1);
    //match [row_id_x] in original name and replace with newName
    var newName = name.replace(rowIdExpression, newrowId);
    return newName;
}
```

Iterate through the children and apply the function (assumption: based on the markup provided; markup wrapped inside a div. Change it according to your needs)

```
$('div').children().each(function(){
    $(this).attr('name', function(){
        return getNewName($(this).attr('name'))
    });
});
```

`input` element will have the new name of `field_id_9[rows][row_id_2][col_id_3]` and `select` element will have the new name of `field_id_11[rows][row_id_4][col_id_15]`